# How to use operator overloading with pointer objects?

Tags: c++

How can i use operator overloading with pointer objects ?

For example, i have a class like this :

```
template <typename T>
class Array
{
    public:
        Array(size_t arrSize) : m_ArrSize(arrSize)
        {
            m_Arr = (T*)calloc(m_ArrSize,sizeof(T));
        }

        ~Array()
        {
            free(m_Arr);
        }

        void changeSize(size_t newSize)
        {
            m_ArrSize = newSize;

            m_Arr = (T*)realloc((void*)m_Arr,m_ArrSize*sizeof(T));
        }

        T& operator[](size_t index)
        {
            return m_Arr[index];
        }

        size_t size(){ return this->m_ArrSize; }
    private:
        Array(){}

        T* m_Arr = nullptr;
        size_t m_ArrSize;
};
```

And i want to use operator[] like this :

```
Array<int>* arr = new Array<int>(16);

arr[0] = 35;
```

How can i use this like this ?

Comment: If this doesn't work, please add the compiler error message. If it compiles, please describe what the issue is exactly.

Comment: No, you cannot overload operators that have only primitive types for parameters (like pointers and integers). They have standard meanings which cannot be changed.

Comment: How would code make a dynamic array of `Array<int>` if it can't use the standard pointer operations?

Comment: I found the result. I used operator overloading like this : (*arr)[0] = 35;

Comment: `arr[0] = 35;` means "resize the first (and only) `Array` to hold 35 elements". `(*arr)[0] = 35;` means "assign 35 to the first element of the `Array`"

Comment: You probably want `Array<int> arr(16);` or similar

Comment: The answer to every question 'how can I do with a pointer what I would do with the pointed-to value' is simply 'dereference the pointer first'.

Comment: @BatuhanGerçek Your code will fail miserably if this were `Array<std::string>`, all due to using `calloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: In reality, please don't use this class, and just use `std::vector` instead, which is _actually_ C++ and hence will work with C++ objects, not just primitive types held-over from C. Also, when declaring an instance of a container that points to its members, why declare _it_ as a pointer too? You shouldn't have to write `new` in nearly any user code. The standard library does all it for you.

Comment: @BatuhanGerçek the result you found (`(*arr)[0] = 35`) does not answer the question you asked. You asked how can you make the syntax `arr[0] = 35;` work, but what you found answers the question how can you use `operator[]` when starting from a pointer. Since you apparently were more interested in the functionality than in the syntax (which is a good viewpoint), you should have asked about the functionality rather than the syntax. Which probably means describing what you want in words, rather than using code as the primary means of communication.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
arr[0] = 35;
```

you are actually accessing the 0th element of an array of `Array` objects which is not what you want to do. (Note that this will compile, and is well defined because there is an object at the 0th index. Using any other index is undefined behavior).

To use the `operator[]` on the *pointed to* `Array` object you can do:

```
(*arr)[0] = 35;
```

or more explicitly:

```
arr->operator[](0) = 35;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use [] you should initiate your class like this :

```
Array<int> arr(16);
```

And then you can use operator [] in such way:

```
arr[0] = 35;
cout << arr[0] << endl;
```

But, if you want to initiate the class dynamically you should use this code:

```
Array<int> *arr = new Array<int>(16);

arr->operator[](0) = 35;

cout << arr->operator[](0) << endl;
```

I hope I helped you.